# how to index a username in mongo with case-insensitively?

Tags: mongodb

I am coding a webservice where users can pick a username that has to be case-insensitive unique. However I want to allow them to use a case-sensitive version of their username.

What is the best way to check at insert that the username doesn't have a case-insensitive duplicate? I currently see 2 ways of doing this:

- storing both a lowercase version and another version with the case entered by the user, and indexing only the lowercase version
- store only the version with the case entered by the user and lowercase it for comparison, which defeats the purpose of the index I suppose

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB 3.4 now includes the ability to make a true case-insensitive index.  It is made by specifying a collation with a strength of 2.

Probably the easiest way to do it is to set a collation on the database itself.  Then all queries inherit that collation and will use it:

```
db.createCollection("cities", { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } } )
db.cities.createIndex( { city: 1 } ) // inherits the default collation
db.cities.find({city:"new york"}) //inherits default collation
```

Or you can do it on an index by index basis:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({city: 1}, {collation: {locale: "en", strength: 2}});
```

And use it like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({city: "new york"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2});
```

For more info: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Comment: anybody knows how to do the .collation in PHP? thanks!

Comment: I think: `find([], ["collation" => ["locale" => "en", "strength" => 2])`.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/

Answer (score 10):

Storing the originally-entered username and a canonical version (lowercase for your app) is perfectly reasonable. Just ensure that the canonical field is updated in your model whenever the username is set, and check for constraint violations via the canonical field's unique index.

Another scenario where this solution (original and canonical field) makes sense is articles, where the same title might be re-used but the slug (for URL's) must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that mongodb will support *case-insensitive indexing* from version **3.4** (soon to be released). See this [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90) and the documentation of [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/collation/).

In the example got from the mentioned ticket, we see that using `collation` with a **strength of 2** in both `createIndex` and `find`, performs a case-insensitve search:

```
> db.myCollection.createIndex({city: 1}, {collation: {locale: "en", strength: 2}});
> db.myCollection.insert({_id: 1, city: "New York"});
> db.myCollection.insert({_id: 2, city: "new york"});
> db.myCollection.find({city: "new york"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2});
{ "_id" : 1, "city" : "New York" }
{ "_id" : 2, "city" : "new york" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Indexing does NOT have anything to do with it, indexing is there to make look up (search) faster.

```
db.userTable.find( { storedUserName: /^userEnteredUserName$/i } );
```

See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mongodb+case+insensitive+search

Comment: Indexing and uniqueness constraints are not mutually exclusive: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue

Comment: I did NOT say they are mutually exclusive, I said that indexing by itself does NOT ensure uniqueness.

Comment: @jmikola And generally it is a bad practice to rely on DB to enforce (unique) constraints that should be check by the application.
call to find() returns a result, DB constraint causes an exception.

Comment: @GermannArlington why is an exception worse than making an additionnal query? It seems much more robust to rely on the db rather than the app. That's what unique indexes are for

Comment: @jmikola Because an exception is just that - "exception(al)", abnormal, out-of-the-ordinary. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception)
In most programming languages exception (generating, progression and handling) consumes considerably more resources and time than most other operations (like querying the database).

Comment: MongoDB index is case-sensitive, to it won't be able to use it efficiently with case-insensitive regexp, see [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/).

Comment: @GermannArlington Disagree; if you don't use the db to enforce uniqueness you will likely run into concurrency issues if your application gets to a non-trivial scale.  The pre-check is not a bad idea *also*, for the reasons  you suggest, but does not remove the need for a unique constraint in the db

Comment: MongoDB indexes can specify uniqueness - db.users.ensureIndex( { userName : 1 }, { unique : true } );

Comment: The point of a case-insensitive index is to make case-insensitive searching faster.