# What is the best practice to check if document with field value exists in MongoDB?

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I was wondering what is the best practice to check if username is already registered. For example I sign up as Peter and I want to prevent other users from using:

- PETER
- pETER
- peter
- PEteR
- peTeR

you've got the idea.
Should I use regex for case-insensitive query using MongoDB in PHP:

```
$username = 'Peter';
$db->users->count(['username' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^'.$username.'\\b', 'i')]);
```

or should I store 2 versions of username, the original version and one lower case version for this purpose?

```
$username = strtolower('Peter');
$query = $db->users->count(['username_lowercase' => $username]);
if ($query > 0) {
    echo 'This username is already used';
}
```

or is there any other approach?

Comment: I would use regex case-insensitive match using `i`, I think it is the best practice for your job, and saves you from duplicate entries in the database.

Comment: @Ibrahim  Hi, thank you for suggestion, that's right but what about performance?

Comment: I would use the second option in order to avoid duplicate entries and better performance while inserting... I don't think using regex on each record will be good for performance

Comment: @AmiHollander thank you for your time and thoughts. I used the RegEx option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding performance, the best approach is always to test and never have prejudice.

A third approach would be to use a case insensitive index with unique constraint. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/ and oh I've found a duplicate of your question [how to index a username in mongo with case-insensitively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865770/how-to-index-a-username-in-mongo-with-case-insensitively)